# 'phonegap' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I am trying to install phonegap 3.1 version using node.js, Command line interface.

Phonegap got installed on the machine, but I am not able to use phonegap command. When I list packages, I can see phonegap, but can not run command to create project.

**System config :**
OS : WIN XP,
node version : 0.10.22,
npm version : 1.3.14,
phonegap version : 3.1.0,

**EDIT :**

**Error Message**

C:>phonegap

'phonegap' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:>npm -g list phonegap

C:\Documents and Settings\vishal.kardode\Application Data\npm
└── phonegap@3.1.0-0.15.0

Comment: How do you install phonegap? It's supposed to be installed as a global package, ie. `npm install -g npm`

Comment: Yes it was installed on global setup, I missed that -g first time, then I installed again with -g,

Comment: What is the console's error message? Does `npm -g list phonegap` output something?

Comment: editec entry for error message

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Problem is you need to set environment variable.

Start -> Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Environment variables

or

Mycomputer -> Right Click -> properties -> Advance System settings -> Environment    variables

under User variables for youruser:

```
Path:
  %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%
  \System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\`

Temp:
  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

If you are copy pasting it wont work. Follow my previous answer to configure this. If you
   are not getting this set up let reply.

Comment: No copy pasting ? you mean type it sir ?

Comment: @VishalKardode where do add `%appdata%\npm` in the above path?

Comment: @SoebSafi add it to your `path` in environment variables

Comment: not working for me. Why did you said previous answer. i am lost on that. can you please post link to previous answer

Answer (score 6):

The Problem with enthronement variable for default path of your your current user. Follow the steps.

1. Click the Start menu and type "regedit" on the search box. This will launch the Windows Registry Editor program.
2. Enter to the following Registry entry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings
3. Select the "Enabled" entry in the right side window. If this entry is there, right-click and select "New" followed by "DWORD Value." Name the value "Enabled."
4. Right-click the "Enabled" entry and click "Modify."
5. Change the number in the "Value" box to "1." This will re-enable WSH.
6. close all opened cmd windows and open a new window.

Comment: Very helpful. It works even when reputation is 0. Mark it as answer please.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error and adding the path to the Environment Variables did the trick.

Just pay attention to the correct path, because in my case it is different from the question.

Look what you get when you do:
`npm -g list phonegap`

In my case it displays:
`c:\usr\local`

So this is the path you need to add to the PATH variable under User variables on the Environment Variables.

Comment: Nice answer. This helped me find the path quite fast. +1

Comment: Perfect. Thank you1

Answer (score 3):

Run CMD as Administrator seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

change the name from phonegap to cordova
You can use the following command to create a project through command line
**cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld**

Answer (score 1):

Delete path variable from "users variable". That worked nicely for me.

Answer (score 0):

One reason may be you are running window command prompt instead of node.js command prompt.
you can simply press window button and then search node.js,it will show you node.js command prompt, run it and then type phonegap command there to check whether the phone gap is properly installed or not.

if you see something like this

Usage: phonegap [options] [commands]
Description:
PhoneGap command-line tool.
Commands:
   help [command]       output usage information
   create         create a phonegap project
    ...

that means phonegap has installed successfully.. you can now execute any phonegap command

Comment: This problem has been solved 3 years ago. Why would you submit this answer now? Please read threads prior to posting.

Comment: because i was stuck in the same problem and got solved by this method so i thought that i may help others too in future that is why i answered this for others who will search for this problem.