# phonegap error i could not able to create android project folder

Tags: cordova

I installed phonegap 2.9.1 from phonegap.com and Installed Node.js, ANT, GIT, JDK. I changed the variables too.

I want to create Android app so I downloaded Cordova too.

But When I trying to use PhoneGap and Cordova its says an error:

Using CLI:

**phonegap**

it says **"phonegap is not recognised as an internal or external commands."**

I tried "['phonegap' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116108/phonegap-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)" But no changes it still showing the same problem.

I am stuck and i am totally new to this.

Comment: Did you install the phonegap using CLI? Just for curosity: Why not using a more updated version like cordova 3.6.3 / 4.0.0 ?

Comment: How to install that?

Comment: It's written in the documentation http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html