# 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, on windows 64 bit system

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I have successfully installed node 8.11.1 and npm 5.6.0
After that I have installed angular CLI also as below

> npm install -g @angular/cli

When I am trying to create project using below command

> ng new MyApp

I am getting error as "ng is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Please provide solution for the same if I am doing anythin wrong please let me know.

Complete details are showing in attached screen shot
[image]

Comment: add your npm's global installation dir to the path

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['phonegap' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116108/phonegap-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Thanks Baao, I have added below directory to my user's path variable. and restarted system, but still getting same error.        
 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin

Comment: @GAJANANJADHAV Instead try to add this path as environment variable for ng - "C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add that installation in your environment variable of your system. Since, you are using windows go to your environment variable ,

1. From the desktop, right click the `Computer icon`.
2. Choose `Properties` from the context menu.
3. Click the `Advanced system settings` link.
4. Click `Environment Variables`. If the `PATH` environment variable does not exist, click `New` and create one
5. In the `Edit Environment Variable`window, specify the value of the `PATH` environment variable. Which should be `C:\users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin`
6. Click `OK`. Close all remaining windows by clicking `OK`.
7. Reopen Command prompt window, and run `ng new MyApp`. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

**ng is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file**

- Many of us has face this error, while working with angular in windows
  system. So to solve this error just in command prompt/Power shell,  u
  have to install the lower version of angular or the same version of
  angular as that of ur project of angular version.

  You have to run command npm i @angular/cli at
  C:\Users\Dell\AppData\roaming\npm>  at this file path and all the
  error of ng will resolved